# JMeter - controller for throughput

Tags: jmeter

I have a webservice requirement that it should be able to process minimum 1000 requests / min.

I can create a JMeter test & call this webservice again and again in a loop to see how many requests were made - for 1 user it is able to make 100 calls in a min, I can increase the user to 10-15 & see if i am able to process minimum 1000 requests / minute or not.

My question is - Is there any controller/method to test this type of requirement - 1000 requests/min (user count can be anything)? (I do not want to increase the user by using trial & error method)

`Throughput controller` - as apache says it is badly named. it is not for this. Can `Constant Throughput Timer` be used for this requirement?

Comment: @negative voters, Please leave the comment if you think this question does not have enough info. I will be happy to provide.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable question to me. The only reason I can think of for a downvote is that you're asking what the function of the Constant Throughput Timer is, and this is very well documented in the User Manual and discussed on SO before. Anyway, upvoting to bring you back to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to you question is, Yes, Constant Throughput timer exactly satisfies what you're asking for. Start with a large number of users, and CTT will insert pauses to ensure the target throughput is met.

CTT of course cannot guarantee that the target throughput will be reached, this depends on the scalability of the application as well, what it really does is prevent the throughput from going *above* the set value. You can also change the set throughput value at runtime if you so desire.

The long answer is that maybe you should consider a constant ramp up type test. The question you are asking is can my application support 1000 req/min. The implied questions are, if not, how much does it really support? If it can do, how much higher can it go before it fails?

A better test to run IMO, is to have the number of users (and hence the throughput) slowly but constantly increase over time, from 0 all the way up to 150% or even 200% desired load.

[image]

If you're monitoring error rate and response times as well, you'll see a sharp increase in response time, or sudden increase in error rate, or a leveling off of throughput even with increasing users - this is where you know the application has reached breaking or plateau point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Usually how long do you run your performance test? 1 hr, 2 hrs...or..until you see a breaking point?   I have decent knowledge in Jmeter - but i do not have performance testing experience / concepts. You suggest any book/site? Thanks again.

Comment: Duration really depends on what you're looking to measure. Response time measurement type tests tend to be 1 hr long. But a hunt for a memory leak can be several hours long. This is a bit old, but the concepts still apply: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx